# How to get android.mk file from decompiled APK?

Tags: android, android.mk

I have an `.apk` I decompiled and I see there are `**.so**` files used in that code.

How do I find the `**.mk**` file from that source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

Build scripts like `build.gradle` and the `.mk`, if there even was one, are used to build the `.apk` but are not included in the output of the build i.e., the packaged `.apk`